# Java Change DNS Server dynamic based on resolv.conf

Tags: java, dns

In requirment, /etc/resolv.conf will be modified by other system. For example, firstly resolv.conf is 1.1.1.1

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

in fact, this can't resolution url by this DNS server

```
InetAddress addr1 = InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");
System.out.println(addr1.getHostAddress());
```

it will throw exception

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: www.google.com: unknown error
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1076)
```

Secondly, we modify the /etc/resolv.conf to nomal dns server

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

continue use code to connect to url

```
InetAddress addr2 = InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");
System.out.println(addr2.getHostAddress());
```

but it still throw exception as above.

I have tried use jndi to get DNS server using in Java, and found that below change resolv.conf and after change, the dnsServer both is 1.1.1.1

```
Hashtable env =  new Hashtable();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory");
DirContext ictx = new InitialDirContext(env);
String dnsServers = (String) ictx.getEnvironment().get("java.naming.provider.url");
System.out.println(dnsServers);
```

So how JVM can using dns server dynamically based on Linux system

Comment: IIRC just changing /etc/reolv.conf does not reload it

Comment: what is IIRC, you mean linux need to reload /etc/resolv.conf, after change

Comment: IIRC - If I Recall Correctly

Comment: you mean linux need to reload /etc/resolv.conf, after change - yes or so I thought

Comment: after change this file, i have try to nslookup this url, and it is successfully get IP, but in running Java, it can't get it.

Comment: very old post but https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=41520

Comment: and i suspect because JVM cache this dns server or use other dns server provider.

Comment: [That answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48787534/are-the-changes-of-file-etc-resolv-conf-immediate) probably explains your problem system-wise, but the question remains how to `res_init` in Java.